# What is the difference between delegation and indirection patterns

Tags: design-patterns

My understanding of [indirection design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352106/difference-between-pure-fabrication-and-indirection)  from GRASP design patterns is that an object is essentially delegating responsibilities that are not cohesive to itself to another object whose sole purpose is to implement that responsibility. So then what is the difference between a delegate design pattern and an indirection design pattern? Aren't they both delegating responsibilities or is the delegate pattern a way to implement an indirection design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

They are the same pattern. The [Wikipedia article redirections from `indirection` to `delegation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Indirection).

It is simply a way of passing objects to a "parent", and having the "parent" delegate/indirect calls to its objects.